# Combining two SQL statements that use three tables and a group by and distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to join multiple tables and also use a group by.  I can either join the three tables, but then cannot use the distinct and group by or I have to dived into two statements.  Is there a way to get this into one statement?

```
Select  FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name
      , Employee.Title as 'Job Title'
      , Employee.EmployeeID
  from Sales.SalesPerson
     , Person.Contact
     , HumanResources.Employee
 where SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=Contact.ContactID 
   and SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=Employee.EmployeeID;

Select Distinct 
       SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
     , Count(Customer.CustomerID) as 'Total Customers'
  From Sales.SalesPerson
     , Sales.Customer
     , Sales.SalesOrderHeader
 Where (SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID) 
   and (Customer.CustomerID=SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID)
 Group by SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
 Order by 'Total Customers' DESC;
```

Comment: You can join three table and using a GROUP BY and/or DISTINCT. However, I'm not clear on why you want to accomplish. The easiest way for us to help is to show us a bare minimum sample data from the three tables and the desired output. Our at least a clear English statement of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using an inline view, as below:

```
Select  
      FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name
      , Employee.Title as "Job Title"
      , Employee.EmployeeID
     , Grouped_Customers.SalesPersonID
     , Grouped_Customers."Total Customers"
  from Sales.SalesPerson
     , Person.Contact
     , HumanResources.Employee,
(
Select 
       SalesPerson.SalesPersonID as SalesPersonID
     , Count(Customer.CustomerID) as "Total Customers"
  From Sales.SalesPerson
     , Sales.Customer
     , Sales.SalesOrderHeader
 Where (SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID) 
   and (Customer.CustomerID=SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID)
 Group by SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
) Grouped_Customers
 where SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=Contact.ContactID 
   and SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=Employee.EmployeeID
   and Grouped_Customers.SalesPersonID = SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
 Order by "Total Customers" DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I needed.  I will have to look up "inline" view.

Comment: You're welcome! Here's a short and simple introduction: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/inline-view.html

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use the following:

```
Select
   SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
 , Count(DISTINCT Customer.CustomerID) as 'Total Customers'
From Sales.SalesPerson
 , Sales.Customer
 , Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Where (SalesPerson.SalesPersonID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID) 
  and (Customer.CustomerID=SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID)
Group by SalesPerson.SalesPersonID
Order by 'Total Customers' DESC;
```

This causes the count to only count distinct customer IDs within a given salespersonID.